# Appropriate way to build my model in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I will use neo4j 2.1.6 to build a web application for telecommunications.

I have started building my model in a UML diagram, describing the relations between each element (for example a Cabinet constsists of NetworkBoards, NetworkBoards consists of Vcards etc.).

My initial idea was to create - from the classes described in my UML - nodes. These nodes will relate to each other as described in the UML. Later I would create instances of these nodes which would contain my data and would be related to each other as their parent classes are (please check UML attachment).

Now I realise maybe this way of thinking is NOT the "neo4j" way. I came up with the idea that I should actually build nodes containing my data and relate these nodes with each other based on the relations I describe in the UML. The nodes will actually group into labels BASED ON the classes I desribe in my UML.

The difference between the two approaches is that in the second I won't create classes described in my UML nodes but only labels with the name of these classes.  I hope what I am trying to say is clear.
What do you think? Which approach is actually more correct and in the philosophy of neo4j?

I am really looking forward to hearing your comments and advice at your earlierst convienience.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a *philosophy* per se; graph databases give you nodes and relationships as primitives to work with different than other databases which might give you other primitives like documents, tables, etc.  There's some [general guidance on modeling with graphs](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-modeling/) that you should definitely check out.

There are a few principles you can steal from books like [Learning Neo4J](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849517169).  You'll still have to interpret for your context.   The first two from that book are "Design for Query-Ability" and "Align relationships with Use Cases".

So the first strong recommendation I have for you is don't build your data model as an abstract model separate from use cases or queries.  Build a list of questions you need to ask of this database.  How to answer these questions easily will guide your process of design.

In your UML setup you seem to be referring to a lot of HAS_A relationships, like a `Cabinet` has a series of `NetworkBoards`, etc.

As a starting point, think of each of your UML classes as a node label in Neo4j.   Class relationships then become neo4j relationships.  This is *general advice only*, it's something you need to adapt in light of your query requirements.  This is roughly similar to your "first idea" you list.  Nothing wrong with that at all, I don't think.

Your second approach sounds very similar to the first. When you build nodes with the data in them, I'm thinking of individual nodes as instances of the UML classes, i.e. a particular `NetworkBoard`.  Class membership itself can usually be a label in Neo4J.  How do you know that something is a `NetworkBoard`?  It has that label.

So...you're not far off, but I think the big missing piece here is your query requirements, and what kinds of questions you need to ask of this database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Perhaps I didn't explain it very clear. In my first approach I meant that I will actually use an abstract model and from this abstract model I will create instances (which you actually say its not a good idea, right?). In the second approach I am thinking of creating labels (based on the name of my classes from UML) which will actually group all the different nodes. I understand this is a more correct way. I don't understand this phrase: "I'm thinking of individual nodes as instances of the UML classes"? Instances is something I was thinking of having in the first appro

Comment: in the first approach. In the second approach I was thinking that my classes will only exist in my model as label names.

Comment: Reading it a couple of times more I think I get it! :) What defines the class of a node is in fact the label. Right? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the label identifies the class. All nodes are individual instances of that class.  So the UML model states that there is a class called "Car".  But a particular node might be a 1995 Honda Civic with a particular VIN number, but still with the label Car

Comment: Its very clear to me now that I have to consider my query requirements before I make the model. But my model is kind of fixed. What I describe can not really change as this is a real-world implementation. For example a fiber wire can only be connected with one way to a network card. I also can not neglect any of my classes (which represent real-world objects). Could this actually mean that my data model can not really build in a strong- relation with my query requirements? Thanks. D.

Comment: Consider your UML as describing a logical data model; consider your neo4j implementation as the physical equivalent.  If you were doing this in an RDBMS, it would be fair game to split some relations out into multiple tables for various reasons.  Your neo4j structure does not have to exactly mimic the UML model, you just have to understand the mappings/differences between them.